# Padding on block elements across multiple printed pages

Tags: css

I am developing styles or an ebook. This includes pullout panels of varying length, some longer than a single printed page. These panels have grey background and a padding of 1em all around. However the padding doesn't affect the top or bottom of the panel if it's broken there because of a page break. For example (* is the padding):

```
***********************
*The first sentence   *
*The second sentence  *
*The third and final  *
*sentence             *
***********************
```

If it's broken across 2 pages it looks like this:

```
***********************
*The first sentence   *
*The second sentence  *
----------------------- (page break)
*The third and final  *
*sentence             *
***********************
```

As you can see the lines of text next to the page breaks are butt up against the edge of the page, rather than fitting comfortably inside the panel.

I want to incorporate additional padding so it looks like this:

```
***********************
*The first sentence   *
*The second sentence  *
***********************
----------------------- (page break)
***********************
*The third and final  *
*sentence             *
***********************
```

Just to reiterate, I want the panels to be able to break across multiple pages, I just want to be able to add extra padding where it breaks. Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure, I'm not up on ebook design, but I don't think you can add padding quite like that. BUT you might try something with [widows](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/widows) and [orphans](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/orphans)

Comment: I know padding will not work in some ebooks, but I've been accessed to include bells and whistles so those apps that can handle them do have them.

Comment: What I am saying is that the CSS can't detect where the page will break to add any padding. This is especially true when text-size can be changed at the users device.

Comment: Fair enough. I don't see a way of using widows and orphans because I have no way of knowing how many elements there will be. Maybe this is a wontfix?

Comment: From my limited knowledge most reader devices handle this just fine by adding margins to the top/bottom of their virtual 'pages'.